# Ignore multiple identical subdirectories with shutil

Tags: python, copy, shutil

Suppose I have the following folder, named `local` and I want to make a recursive copy of it, using `python 3.7` and the `shutil` library. The `local` folder has always the same inner structure.

```
.
├── local/
    ├── A/
    |   ├── img/     
    |   |    ├── 1.jpg
    |   |    ├── ...
    |   |    └── n.jpg     
    |   |
    |   └── txt/
    |        ├── text_1.txt
    |        ├── ...
    |        └── text_n.txt
    ├── B/
    .   ├── img/     
    .   |    ├── 1.jpg
    .   |    ├── ...
        |    └── n.jpg     
        |
        └── txt/
             ├── text_1.txt
             ├── ...
             └── text_n.txt
```

Using the `shutil` library and its `copy` method, how do you write the `ignore_patterns` arguments if you want to obtain the following `remote` structure (recursively ignoring the `img` folder *in each subfolder*) :

```
.
├── remote/
    ├── A/
    |   └── txt/
    |        ├── text_1.txt
    |        ├── ...
    |        └── text_n.txt
    ├── B/
    .   └── txt/
    .        ├── text_1.txt
    .        ├── ...
             └── text_n.txt
```

Naively, I tried `shutil.copytree('local', 'remote', ignore=shutil.ignore_patterns('local/*/img'))` but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It worked for me.

```
import fnmatch
import os
import shutil


class YourClassCopy:
    def __init__(self, patterns=[]):
        self.patterns = patterns

    def _logpath(self, path, names):
        if len(self.patterns) == 0:
            return []  # nothing to exclude

        ignored_names = []
        for f in names:
            for pattern in self.patterns:
                if os.path.abspath(os.path.join(path, f)) == pattern \
                   or fnmatch.fnmatch(f, pattern):
                    ignored_names.append(f)

        return set(ignored_names)

    def execute_copy(self, src, dest):
        shutil.copytree(src, dest, ignore=self._logpath)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the code you posted it appears your `local` and `remote` directories are relative to your script, so how about the following:

```
from shutil import copytree, ignore_patterns

# also use an absolute path below, prefix with r'<Absolute Path...>'
source = 'local' 
destination = 'remote'

copytree(
    src=source,
    dst=destination,
    ignore=ignore_patterns('img')
)
```

The `shutil` module already contains the `ignore_patterns()` function, so there is no need to create your own function...

And prefixing a path with `r''` creates a raw string which treats backslashes as a literal character so you do not need to escape them.